# How to specify schema while reading parquet file with pyspark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

While reading a parquet file stored in hadoop with either scala or pyspark an error occurs:

```
#scala    
var dff = spark.read.parquet("/super/important/df")
    org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:189)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$8.apply(DataSource.scala:189)
      at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:387)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:441)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:425)
  ... 52 elided
```

or

```
sql_context.read.parquet(output_file)
```

results in the same error.

Error message is pretty clear about what has to be done:  *Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.;*. 
But where can I specify it?

Spark 2.1.1, Hadoop 2.5, dataframes are created with a help of pyspark. Files are partitioned into 10 peaces.

Comment: Can you try this var dff = spark.read.parquet("/super/important/df").toDF("ColumnName1,"ColumnName2")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you try to read an empty directory as parquet.
If for example you create an empty DataFrame, you write it in parquet and then read it, this error appears.
You could check if the DataFrame is empty with `rdd.isEmpty()` before write it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a quick implementation for the same

[image]

**Hope this Helps!!...**

Comment: would consider an upvote if this was code and not a screenshot, but just cant...